# DataGridComboBoxColumn is empty if text does not exist in the dropdown

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am using the WPF Toolkit DataGrid bound to Person collection. The LastName is represented by the ComboBox with wellknown names.

```
<x:Array x:Key="knownLastNames" Type="sys:String">
    <sys:String>Johnson</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Williams</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

The problem is that if I set LastName to "Brown" (missed in knownLastNames), the ComboBox column is empty.

```
<dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="LastName" TextBinding="{Binding LastName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource knownLastNames}}" />
```

If I make the ComboBox editable, I can see "Brown", but only when in edit mode (pressed F2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that I have already raised in [the forums](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=46627) and confirmed via email with Vincent (a coordinator on the project). I ended up writing my own custom column type just so I could do editable `ComboBox`es.

Comment: The answer posed by Beretta1979 in the forum post did the trick for me.